# C# Append data to xlsx

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, append

I've been searching the web on how to append data to an xlsx fil, but I really can't figure out how to do that? There are tons of ways to write to xlsx files, but neither is working for me.

I have a xlsx file and i want to store two strings and an integer from my C# WPF application. Something like this:

```
[FolderName][19-03-2012][20-03-2012]
[John      ][1234      ][2568      ]
[Bob       ][4568      ][5275      ]
```

If john already exists then append the integer and the string to something like this:

```
[FolderName][19-03-2012][20-03-2012][21-03-2012]
[John      ][1234      ][2568      ][2665858   ]
[Bob       ][4568      ][5275      ]
```

If Hugo doesn't exist then write to the excel file like this:

```
[FolderName][19-03-2012][20-03-2012][21-03-2012][22-03-2012]
[John      ][1234      ][2568      ][2665858   ][          ]
[Bob       ][4568      ][5275      ][          ][          ]
[Hugo      ][          ][          ][          ][123548    ]
```

The [ ] are cells in excel fill :-)

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT**

I'm using OleDbConnection and working with xls instead of xlsx. I've realized that xls can be used as a "database". I'm now able to read, update, insert and select from my xls file. However, using this:

```
var myCommand = new OleDbCommand("Select [Share] From [Q1 2012$]", myConnection);
```

gives me all the data from the column "Share", but it is possible to select data from column "A" or column B or C? If you know what i mean?

Comment: Seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472959/c-how-to-access-an-excel-cell ?

Comment: It would help if you could show the code of how you are trying to do it now, and what error it is giving you. Like you said, there are many ways of accomplishing this, and many possible reasons for the problems you're encountering.

Comment: Right now i'm at point zero. I'm guessing that i have to open and read the content of the xlsx file, check if the string exists in the first column, append to the row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be using the OpenXML SDK:
[read about OpenXML](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/6170/read-and-write-open-xml-files-ms-office-2007/)

which gives you strongly-typed classes to manipulate it.

[Download the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124)

Answer (score 0):

If you need both .xls and .xlsx support, you may wish to consider [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com/) as well. It has a sophisticated API for manipulating Excel files, but may be overkill for what you need. It is also not free, but there is a free trial.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the engineers who built the latest version.