# Read Rows in Excel File using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, unit-testing

I have  added an Excel file to provide unit test values.

Below is a example about what I was doing before

```
public void test1()
{
    try
    {
        var Service = new Service.ServiceClient();
        var Cid = testContextInstance.DataRow["CId"].ToString();
        var MNumber = testContextInstance.DataRow["MNumber"].ToString();
        var VID = testContextInstance.DataRow["VID"].ToString();
        var isVisit = new Service.ISVisit()
        {
        };

    var first = Service.Medis(isVisit).Cast<Service.ISMedi>().FirstOrDefault();
    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("12345678", first.Proc.ProcID);
    }
```

.i am using excel sheet to provide values for the untitest.

[image]

By using the sample code above i am able to loop through each row in the excel and set values to the variables.But the Requirement is not to attach excel as a Data Driven Source and not to use Oledb way to query things in Excel.They said me to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; .

Can any one help me with how to change the code to retrive the data in excel , row by row and assign cells to respective variables using  different approach.??? This is a c# Unittest framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.11).aspx.

This might be a duplicate of the [C#: How to access an Excel cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472959/c-how-to-access-an-excel-cell), which has examples in the answers using Interop.

**Warning**

Because you mention webservices and Office interop in the same question:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 for more information.

**OOXml**

If possible, you should be using [OOXml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), which is the recommended way to work with Office documents programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give a try to rpa tools? It's much easier there.
Here is the code in one of the rpa tool of G1ANT.

```
addon msoffice version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0
excel.open ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\challenge.xlsx
for ♥n from 1 to 10 step 1
excel.getrow ♥n 
dialog  ♥result
end
```

This robot will store the data in "result" in list format, you can copy and paste the code to the studio.